# Not able to submit a form to the action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have this function in the javascript

```
txJ$(document).ready(function () {


    //txJ$(".submit").closest("form").submit(function (e) {
    txJ$(".submit").closest("form").submit(function (event) {
        //check for encryption key
        { TxEncrypt(event); }
    });
});

function TxEncrypt(event)
{ //perform encryption of token data, then submit the form like normal

    //obtain public key and initial JSEncrypt object
    var txPubKey = '123';
    var txEncrypter = new JSEncrypt();
    txEncrypter.setPublicKey(txPubKey);

    //get Data and encrypt it
    var txData = '{}';
    var txCryptData = '';
    if(txJ$(".data").length > 1)
    { //if there are more than one element with this class, convert it to json string
        txData = txJ$(".data").serializeObject();
        txCryptData = txEncrypter.encrypt(JSON.stringify(txData));
    }
    else
    {   //else, just encrypt the value
        txData = txJ$(".data").val();
        txCryptData = txEncrypter.encrypt(txData);
    }


    dataString = txCryptData;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params=dataString;
    var token;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200) {
    token=xhr.responseText;
    alert(token);
    //add value/field to form
    txCvv = txJ$(".cvv").val();

    var MyForm = txJ$(".submit").closest("form");

        txJ$('<input type="hidden">').attr({
                id: 'token',
                name: 'token'
            }).val(token).appendTo(MyForm);
        txJ$('<input type="hidden">').attr({
                id: 'cvv',
                name: 'cvv'
            }).val(txCvv).appendTo(MyForm);

    //scrub data that we do not want to post
    txJ$(".data").removeAttr('name');
    txJ$(".cvv").removeAttr('name');
        }
    }
    xhr.open('POST', 'tokenize.php', true);
    xhr.send(params); 
    event.preventDefault();



}
```

The form is

```
<form method="POST" action="pp.php">

<input type="text" class="data" name="ccnumber" value="4242424242424242" />
<input type="text" class="cvv" name="cvv" />



<input type="submit" class="submit"  value="tokenize" />

</form>
```

What the script does is,get the value from the input field with data as class and process it from xmlhttpsrequest and get a token from the server and append the token as hidden field in the form and then submits the forms.This is what I wanted to do.

when I click the submit button , all of this happens.

But obviously as there is `event.preventDefault();` the form will not get submitted to action as normal.But if I remove `event.preventDefault();`,the hidden fields are not getting appended,more over xmlhttprequest is not being sent.

I tried `MyForm.submit();` inside the `if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200) {`,but what it does is call the same function again and again.

Is there some way I can submit the form to the action (not call this function) after the function has run?

Comment: how/where you call js function?

Comment: This is a small part of the code,there is some other functions in the javascript code.This is final function which is called inside the javascript.The submit has a class "submit" which calls the javascript function

Comment: @RakeshSharma Please see the updated code of javascript

Comment: @RakeshSharma Any chance?

Comment: check my answer and try it and let me know

Comment: @RakeshSharma Thank you so much for the answer.But I wont be able to add the id tag to the form or any modification there as I have many clients using the script I have given.Any modification can be done on the script only which is at my server.So using this wont be btter solutin.is there someway I can do anything in my code would be so much helpful

Comment: @RakeshSharma I get it worked. I made the xmlhttpsrequest as synchronous and removed prevent default

Comment: Hi, :) glad to know working now also check my updated answer may be useful for further btw meets again same last name

Comment: :D Yeah hehe..If you are free helping out people,I have another issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108323/form-inout-getting-appended-after-the-submit-button   :D

Comment: @RakeshSharma Yeah ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am giving you code example you need to refine and do your stuff with code
First add an `id="myform"` to form

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myform").submit(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault(); // stop refresh form
      // get your data and do your stuff with that
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "tokenize.php",
               // send your data will be post
                data: {
                    name: "Rakesh",
                    time: "2pm"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                   // remove elements from form
                      $('.data').remove();
                      $('.cvv').remove();
                    // adding a hidden field to form
                     $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "something").attr('value', "something").appendTo($('.submit').closest('form'));

                }
            });
    });
});
```